# How to add standard and user defined objects?

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to do operator overloading for +(addition) operator to add my user defined datatype objects .
Following is the code for that.

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex {
    int i;
    double f;
public:
    complex(int ii=0,double ff=0){
        i = ii;
        f = ff;
    }
    complex operator+(complex object) {
        complex result;
        result.i = this->i + object.i;
        result.f = this->f + object.f;
        return result;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << i <<"\t"<< f;
        cout << endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    complex obj1(1,1.1),obj2(2,2.2),obj3;
    int i(5);
    obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
    obj3.display();
    obj3 = obj3 + i;
    obj3.display();
    obj3 = i + obj3;//generates me compiler error
    obj3.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I have learnt that when I do obj1 + obj2,it is expanded by the compiler as obj1.operator+(obj2);
So that part of code works fine.

But when I do add an int and complex ,I think it get expanded as i.operator(obj1).

So it gives me compiler errors.

Should I define operator+ function in int class or how to solve this?
Please suggest,
Thank you,

Comment: I suggest that you read somewhere about what operators generally can be, and what should be, implemented as free functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to provide an overloaded version of `+` which takes `int` and class `complex` object as input parameters. This function should be a non member function.

```
complex operator+(int i, complex object)
```

Note that additionally, if you want to access `protected` or `private` members inside this overloaded function then it will have to be made `friend` of your `complex` class.

This is a peculiar example of the strength of free functions used for operator overloading as against member function operator overloads.

Comment: Since there exists a conversion from `int` to `complex`, having such an overload would be quite redondant. The usual solution is to make the `operator+(UDT, UDT)` a free function, not to add overloads for all the types that can be converted to the UDT.

Comment: @LucTouraille: I wouldn't recommend Implicit conversion constructors for the simple reason that I wouldn't want implicit conversions wreaking havoc.Believe me they do.Also, Incidentally, OP has a conversion constructor here which may not be the case always.

Comment: I usually advocate the use of `explicit` constructors, to disallow implicit conversion, but the implicit conversion in this case, from integer to complex, seems reasonable, don't you think?

Comment: @LucTouraille: It depends,depends on the project how big or small it is and also on the level of expertise of the programmers working on it.Exposing new programmers to perils of Implicit conversions in a big complex project is an maintenance nightmare i would avoid.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason why the `operator+` is usually defined as a free function: instead of having `complex complex::operator+(complex object)`, you could (should) define a free function

```
complex operator+(const & complex lhs, const & complex rhs)
{
    return complex(lhs.i + rhs.i, lhs.j + rhs.j);
    // You will need some way to access i and j, either by making this function
    // a friend of complex or by providing getters
}
```

This way, the line `obj3 = i + obj3` will be equivalent to `operator+(i, obj3)`; since an integer can be converted to a complex thanks to the constructor you wrote, the call will succeed and be equivalent to this one: `operator+(complex(i), obj3)`.

As a rule of thumb, you should prefer free functions over member functions to overload binary operators when the left hand side and the right hand size have equal importance. This way, you know that if `a op b` works then `b op a` will work too.

On a sidenote, you should also prefer passing your parameters as reference-to-const, and mark your member functions as const when they are (like `operator+` and `display` in your sample).

Answer (score 0):

Define a function outside any class:

```
complex operator + (int lhs, complex rhs) { /* ... */ }
```

Make sure the compiler can see it, and you can add ints to complexes to your heart's content. You probably also want one with the parameters the other way around.